# Iterate Large XML File and Copy Select Nodes

Tags: c#, xpath

I need to iterate through a large XML file (~2GB) and selectively copy certain nodes to one or more separate XML files.

My first thought is to use XPath to iterate through matching nodes and for each node test which other file(s) the node should be copied to, like this:

```
var doc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\Some\Path.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var nodeIter = nav.Select("//NodesOfInterest"); 
while (nodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    foreach (Thing thing in ThingsThatMightGetNodes)
    {
        if (thing.AllowedToHaveNode(nodeIter.Current))
        {
            thing.WorkingXmlDoc.AppendChild(... nodeIter.Current ...);
        }
    }
}
```

In this implementation, `Thing` defines `public System.Xml.XmlDocument WorkingXmlDoc` to hold nodes that it is `AllowedToHave()`. I don't understand, though, how to create a new XmlNode that is a copy of nodeIter.Current.

If there's a better approach I would be glad to hear it as well.

Comment: To use XPath on a 2GB XML document your computer must have > 10GB RAM, maybe > 16GB. Is this the case?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Yes it does, I wasn't aware that XPath requires so much RAM and that seems quite wasteful (it's a server, and other processes would certainly suffer).  Can you suggest a different solution?

Comment: I recommend using an XmlReader -- thus you aren't limited for RAM. Your logic will remain largely the same.

Comment: I know its is hard to change the design at some point, but the problem,I think, is in using xml as a DB. I would change my design,use a real DB and select the nodes easily.

Comment: @L.B The XML file comes from a partner company.  I'm actually iterating it to insert appropriate records in a DB.

Comment: @EricJ. then hard to code `XmlReader` is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluation of an XPath expression requires that the whole XML document (XML Infoset) be in RAM.

For an XML file whose textual representation exceeds 2GB, typically more than 10GB of RAM should be available just to hold the XML document.

Therefore, while not impossible, it may be preferrable (especially on a server that must have resources quickly available to many requests) to use another technique.

The XmlReader (based classes) is an excellent tool for this scenario. It is fast, forward only, and doesn't require to retain the read nodes in memory. Also, your logic will remain almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider LINQ to XML.  Check this blog post for details and examples:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2007/12/11/linq-to-xml-over-large-documents.aspx

Comment: How does LINQ to XML perform with ~2GB input files?

Comment: Straight up, probably not so great.  But you can operate against a stream.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx#Y1392.

Answer (score 0):

Try an XQuery processor that implements document projection (an idea first published by Marion and Simeon). It's implemented in a number of processors including Saxon-EE. Basically, if you run a query such as //x, it will filter the input event stream and build a tree that only contains the information needed to handle this query; it will then execute the query in the normal way, but against a much smaller tree. If this is a small part of the total document, you can easily reduce the memory requirement by 95% or so.